# Jquery .load div content and find div id remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, removeclass, jquery-load

I need help understanding what I'm doing wrong. I'm loading a page and grabbing two divs using .load works great no issues. but then I want to find one of those divs and remove the bootstrap class and possibly add another class .addClass() howeve rI can't even get the removeClass to work. Am I doing this correctly?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#siteloader").load( "/men/Maria-Brown #qvImage, #qvContent" );
  $("#qvImage").removeClass(" .col-xs-12");
});
```

Comment: even if I remove the .dot out of .col-xs-12 so it looks like this here .removeClass("col-xs-12"); it still doesn't work by the way.

Comment: please share the html code as well

Comment: Is the file getting loaded in correctly?

Comment: yes there isn't any errors on the page and the two divs load fine into the popup. this is a quick product view popup that loads a div from another location on the same server using .load function.

Comment: And you said that removing the `.` for `col-xs-12` in the `removeClass()` method didn't work either? Also can you confirm that the div has that class to begin with?

Comment: I tried this in my console and it seemed to remove the class: `$("#qvImage").removeClass("col-xs-12");`

Comment: i know it's weird it works in console but doesn't work in the page. look right under the #qvImage div and #qvContent div I have the <script> right there that shows the same thing you said to do. just doesn't work on page load or something. can't figure it out.

Comment: I took a look at your code and it looks like you have the `<script/>` nested in this div: `.cd-slider-wrapper`. You usually wanna put the script in its own `.js` file or put your `<script></script>` just before the closing of the `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

Awww yes I figured it out. because the main.js loads the popup and has it set to hidden until the popup is triggered. the

```
  $("#qvImage").removeClass("col-xs-12");
```

needed to be added to the function inside the main.js now it works great.
thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I am not a really good understanding guy in all aspects of jquery, but I think I have one suggestion that you should check:

```
             $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#siteloader").load( "/men/Maria-Brown #qvImage, #qvContent", function(){
$("#qvImage").removeClass(" .col-xs-12");
              } );

             });
```

so this means that you run the "removeClass()" function AFTER the load is done. Try it.. I think this should help.
I can't write the comments yet, so I'm writing it as an Answer...